# convert h264 avcc stream to SampleBuffer in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, h.264

How do I convert h264 avcc stream to SampleBuffer in iOS 8

Need the sample buffer to perform decompression session

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in Mpeg-4 format. You will need an algorithm to read the raw byte stream looking for NAL separator codes (usually 00000001) and then look for the NAL unit code in the next byte.

Typical NAL Unit codes are 67 (PPS), 68 (SPS), 41 (P Frame) and 65 (I Frame)

Generally the first will be the SPS, capture these bytes in an NSMutable Data, then capture the PPS in another. use CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets with the SPS and PPS data to create a CMFormatDescription.

Use the CMFormatDescription to create a VTDecompressionSession using VTDecompressionSessionCreate.
When you have these, capture the NALUnit payload into a CMBlockBuffer making sure to replace the separator code with a 4 byte length code (the length of the NalUnit including the unit code) and then using this and the Format Description you created before, create a CMSampleBuffer.

You now have everything you need to use VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame.

Comment: You will need to add a CMTimingInfo struct when creating your SampleBuffer, this will have the Presentation Time Stamp expressed as a CMTime object.

Comment: what do I need to put in the presentation time stamp ?

Comment: This is an old post and don't know if its solved by now or not. But avcc format does not use 00000001 rule to store NAL units. One needs to check for extra data to be able to parse NAL units of avcc h264. I think you may correct the (usually 00000001) part